# SharePoint 2013 JSLink OnPostRender not working after adding SP.SOD.executeFunc

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, jslink

I use JSLink to color rows in a SharePoint 2013 list

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilBodyLoaded(function () {
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {

        RegisterModuleInit(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/SiteAssets/jsLink.js", Highlight); 
        Highlight();
    }
  });

});
function Highlight() {   

var HighlightFieldCtx = {};
HighlightFieldCtx.Templates = {};
HighlightFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {};  

HighlightFieldCtx.OnPostRender =  postRenderHandler;     

 SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(HighlightFieldCtx);  
}


function postRenderHandler(ctx)
{

 var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;


 for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
{
    // do stuff
    row.classList.add("Color");


}

}
```

I need add *SP.SOD.executeFunc()* for activate *_spPageContextInfo*. But when I added SP.SOD.executeFunc(), function postRenderHandler not called in line with *HighlightFieldCtx.OnPostRender =  postRenderHandler*. 
When I dont have *SP.SOD.ExecuteFunc()* and static link on my JS and CSS, my code and rendering fully working. Can you please help me, how to make proper code with working *_spPageContextInfo*?

Comment: Are you wanting to add color to only certain rows? Are you coloring every other row just to make it easier to see which row the data pertains to (color, no color, color, etc..)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
                //alert(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl);
                RegisterModuleInit(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/SiteAssets/jsLink.js", Highlight);
                Highlight();
            });

        function Highlight() {

            var HighlightFieldCtx = {};
            HighlightFieldCtx.Templates = {};
            HighlightFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {};
            HighlightFieldCtx.OnPostRender =  postRenderHandler;
            SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(HighlightFieldCtx);
        }

        function postRenderHandler(ctx)
        {
            var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
            alert('postRenderHandler');
        }
    </script>
```